# How to I make it so my enemy doesn't change it's height when the target jumps?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been writing a script for enemy movement in my game, but when the target(Player) jumps, the enemy begins to gradually float up to the same y position the target was in. I would like it if the enemy stayed at the same position as the ground, but I have not found out how I would be able to do that. I am new to Unity, so the only thing I could think of was adding a rigidbody to the enemy but that did not seem to work. Would anyone have any Idea on how to do this? Here is my script:

```
 public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour {
 //target
 public Transform Player;
 //the distace the enemy will begin walking towards the player
 public float walkingDistance = 10.0f;
 //the speed it will take the enemy to move
 public float speed = 10.0f;
 private Vector3 Velocity = Vector3.zero;
 void Start(){
 }
 void Update(){
     transform.LookAt (Player);
     //finding the distance between the enemy and the player
     float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position);
     if(distance < walkingDistance){
         //moving the enemy towards the player
         transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, 
Player.position, ref Velocity, speed);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `y` value before doing the movement

```
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    //target
    public Transform Player;
    //the distace the enemy will begin walking towards the player
    public float walkingDistance = 10.0f;
    //the speed it will take the enemy to move
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    private Vector3 Velocity = Vector3.zero;
    void Start(){
    }
    void Update(){
        transform.LookAt (Player);
        Vector3 target = Player.position;
        target.y = transform.position.y;
        //finding the distance between the enemy and the player
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target);
        if(distance < walkingDistance){
        //moving the enemy towards the player
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, 
        target, ref Velocity, speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: `goto` is a C# keyword. Don't use it as a variable name.